# Spring Kafka: Transactional producer error handling

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a Kafka spring application with a read-process-write pattern. I want to make sure that the Kafka transaction rolls back if there are any producer errors so that the record is re-consumed using a SeekToCurrentErrorHandler. The default behavior seems to be to log the producer error and continue processing/commit. To override this default behaviour, i have implemented a ProducerListener that throws an exception in the onError method. Is this the recommended approach for ensuring a rollback and the intent behind spring providing us with the listener hook?

Logs showing an exception followed by a commit (The exception didnt result in a rollback)

```
2020-04-02 18:20:18.314|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                                o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|TRACE|                                 456|              d3410ae8-c964-41e7-98be-6706a6f2b3b2| Sending: ProducerRecord
2020-04-02 18:20:18.345|[                      kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-13]|                           org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata|ERROR|                                    |                                                  | [Producer clientId=producer-13, transactionalId=tx-0] Topic authorization failed for topics 
2020-04-02 18:20:18.354|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener|ERROR|                                 456|              d3410ae8-c964-41e7-98be-6706a6f2b3b2| Exception thrown when sending a message with key='170854907' org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [loyalty-retail-outlet-trans-resp-dev1]
2020-04-02 18:20:18.367|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|      o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|INFO |                                    |                                                  | Sending offsets to transaction: {loyalty-retail-outlet-earn-req-dev-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2220, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
2020-04-02 18:20:18.368|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|TRACE|                                    |                                                  | CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@5abb103c, txId=tx-0] sendOffsetsToTransaction({loyalty-retail-outlet-earn-req-dev-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2220, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}, earn-unit-test)
2020-04-02 18:20:18.769|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager|DEBUG|                                    |                                                  | Initiating transaction commit
2020-04-02 18:20:18.769|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|DEBUG|                                    |                                                  | CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@5abb103c, txId=tx-0] commitTransaction()
2020-04-02 18:20:18.816|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|TRACE|                                    |                                                  | CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@5abb103c, txId=tx-0] close(PT5S)
```

The records are produced within a Kafka listener using Kafka Template (read-process-write pattern).

Kafka Template config

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Integer, TransactionResponse> kafkaTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<Integer, TransactionResponse> producerFactory
            , ProducerListener<Integer, TransactionResponse> producerListener) {
        KafkaTemplate<Integer, TransactionResponse> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
//        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(producerListener);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: tx-
      acks: all
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      properties:
        enable.idempotence: true
        delivery.timeout.ms: 180000
```

listener

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "${earn.request.topic}", clientIdPrefix = "EarnConsumer", containerFactory = "earnListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(List<TransactionRequest> requestList,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) String groupId,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partitions,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offsets,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
```

send response method (executes within the listener code)

```
    public void sendResponse(TransactionResponse transactionResponse) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(earnResponseTopic, transactionResponse.getEventSummary().getMemberId(), transactionResponse);
    }
```

container config

```
   @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, EarnTransactionRequest> earnListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<Integer, EarnTransactionRequest> consumerFactory
            , SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler seekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler
            , KafkaTransactionManager ktm
    ) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, EarnTransactionRequest> containerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        containerFactory.setBatchListener(true);
        containerFactory.setBatchErrorHandler(seekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler);
        containerFactory.setConcurrency(numConcurrentConsumers);

        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(ktm);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setLogContainerConfig(true);
        containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(true);

        return containerFactory;
    }
```

**EDIT: Simplified application**

@Component
public class QuickTest {

```
private final String responseTopic;
private final KafkaTemplate<Integer, TransactionResponse> kafkaTemplate;

public QuickTest(@Value("${response.topic}") String responseTopic
        , KafkaTemplate<Integer, TransactionResponse> kafkaTemplate) {
    this.responseTopic = responseTopic;
    this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "${request.topic}", clientIdPrefix = "Consumer")
public void listen(TransactionRequest requestList) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(responseTopic, 123456789, null);
}
```

}

**Logs from start of one transaction to other**

```
2020-04-03 19:04:54.901|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|      o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|TRACE|Processing ConsumerRecord(topic = req-dev, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 4, offset = 2185, CreateTime = 1585642853682, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 184, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {})

2020-04-03 19:04:54.901|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager|DEBUG|Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

2020-04-03 19:04:54.901|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|DEBUG|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] beginTransaction()

2020-04-03 19:04:54.901|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager|DEBUG|Created Kafka transaction on producer [CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1]]

2020-04-03 19:04:54.902|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|             o.s.k.l.a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter|DEBUG|Processing [GenericMessage [payload={"eventSummary": {"eventId": "102"}}]]

2020-04-03 19:04:54.902|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                                o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|TRACE|Sending: ProducerRecord(topic= resp-test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=123456789, value=null, timestamp=null)

2020-04-03 19:04:54.902|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|TRACE|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] send(ProducerRecord(topic= resp-test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=123456789, value=null, timestamp=null))

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[                       kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-8]|                        o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient|WARN |[Producer clientId=producer-8, transactionalId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 22 : { resp-test=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[                       kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-8]|                           org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata|ERROR|[Producer clientId=producer-8, transactionalId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] Topic authorization failed for topics [ resp-test]

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener|ERROR|Exception thrown when sending a message with key='123456789' and payload='null' to topic  resp-test:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [ resp-test]
2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                                o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|DEBUG|Failed to send: ProducerRecord(topic= resp-test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=123456789, value=null, timestamp=null)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [ resp-test]
2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                                o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|TRACE|Sent: ProducerRecord(topic= resp-test, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key=123456789, value=null, timestamp=null)

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|      o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|TRACE|Ack: ConsumerRecord(topic = req-dev, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 4, offset = 2185, CreateTime = 1585642853682, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 184, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {"eventSummary": {"eventId": "102"}})

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|      o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|DEBUG|Sending offsets to transaction: {req-dev-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2186, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}

2020-04-03 19:04:54.928|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|TRACE|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] sendOffsetsToTransaction({req-dev-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2186, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}, g21)

2020-04-03 19:04:55.043|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager|DEBUG|Initiating transaction commit

2020-04-03 19:04:55.043|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|DEBUG|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] commitTransaction()

2020-04-03 19:04:55.090|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|TRACE|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] close(PT5S)

2020-04-03 19:04:55.091|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|      o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|TRACE|Processing ConsumerRecord(topic = req-dev, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 4, offset = 2186, CreateTime = 1585644055280, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 184, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = {"eventSummary": {"eventId": "104"})

2020-04-03 19:04:55.091|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                             o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager|DEBUG|Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT

2020-04-03 19:04:55.091|[ org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]|                         o.s.k.c.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory|DEBUG|CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@43926a5b, txId=transactionx-g21.req-dev.1] beginTransaction()
```

Comment: This was a good find. Helped with something similar I was facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error handler runs within the transaction. You should leave it null and the AfterRolllbackProcessor will reseek the records. See the Transactions chapter in the reference manual.

The container needs a `KafkaTransactionManager`.

See [Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions) and [After-Rollback Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#after-rollback).

You should not need to do anything in a `ProducerListener`.

**EDIT**

I added authorization configuration to get a `TopicAuthorizationException` and everything worked as I would have expected (the commit fails)...

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "ktest24", topics = "ktest24")
public void listen(String in) {
    System.out.println("1:" + in);
    this.template.send("ktest24-out", "sendInTx");
}
```

```
1:foo
2020-04-03 14:10:26.619 ERROR 75695 --- [est24.ktest24.0] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener   
 : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='sendInTx' to topic ktest24-out:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [ktest24-out]

2020-04-03 14:10:26.619 ERROR 75695 --- [  ktest24-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer
 : Send offsets to transaction failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [ktest24-out]

2020-04-03 14:10:26.620 ERROR 75695 --- [  ktest24-0-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory  
 : commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@84412c5, txId=tx-ktest24.ktest24.0]
2020-04-03 14:10:31.627 ERROR 75695 --- [  ktest24-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer
 : Transaction rolled back
1:foo
...
```

Comment: Gary - I have currently configued a SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler & KafkaTransactionManager for the container. The SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler is reseeking the records in case of an exception.  Should i be using After-rollback Processor instead of SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler? What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Gary - I have also added the logs showing that the TopicAuthorizationException on the producer did not result in a rollback. The exception just got logged. Will using an After-Rollback processor help in this case?

Comment: Gary - Thanks for your inputs but i need some more guidance on this. The problem seems to be that the "TopicAuthorizationException" on the producer is not causing a rollback - Instead the logs show that we are sending Offsets to transaction followed by a commit.  There is nothing wrong with the records being sent - I am producing to a topic that doesnt exist. I was under the impression that any exception on the producer side would cause the kafka transaction to rollback automatically so that the input record from input topic can be redelivered.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the kafka-clients to me - publishing is asynchronous (although it's a bit strange that the producer listener error is running on the container thread). I would have expected the commit to throw an exception. Can you edit the question to show your publishing code within the listner? It would also be helpful if you could provide guidance about how to configure things to get a `TopicAuthorizationException` so I can reproduce locally.

Comment: Gary - i am producing to a topic name that i know doesnt exist (doing this gives me TopicAuthorizationException). I have provided the config/code details in the question.

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected for me; see the edit.

Comment: Gary - I wrote code similar to yours and still see a commit instead of a rollback. Please take a look at my last edit. I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.. Somewhat strangely the logs show a "o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|DEBUG|Failed to send: ProducerRecord" message followed by a "o.s.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate|TRACE|Sent: ProducerRecord" message.

Comment: Please post your complete simple project someplace, e.g. GitHub, so I can figure out what's different.

Comment: Gary - I have uploaded a simple project to https://github.com/ankush-koul/transactional-producer-test ... The log.txt file shows the logs i receive (timeout exception followed by a commit).

Comment: Thanks; interesting; I see the problem and opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1437) if you want to track it.

Comment: Fixed - try 2.3.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT - BTW you can reduce that 60 second wait by setting the `max.block.ms` producer property.

Comment: Gary - Thank you!

Comment: Thank YOU for your patience with this one.